# How to get response from USB Device after using UsbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer

Tags: android, android-usb

So basically what is happening is I have a tablet connected to a printer that I send files to using UsbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer. I can successfully send the file and everything works but the printer is supposed to send a return code after it has completed the printing. bulkTransfer will only return 0 or the number of bytes that is transferred but not the response file that I want.

```
connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, bytes, bytes.length, TIMEOUT)
```

How do I get the response file from the printer after executing this? Thank you very much!